# Is there a way to prevent onSnapshot to get triggered when using updateDoc?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that the point of using `onSnapshot` is to reflect the remote changes on every opened app instances.
The problem is that I noticed `onSnapshot` is triggered even on the instance that uses `updateDoc` which is not needed in my case because my app is reactive and UI is already updating when local objects' state changes.

I wouldn't care and just ignore this event if I weren't trying to reduce the potential bill as much as possible.

Is there a way to just disable `onSnapshot` while a push is being made on the same instance?

I was thinking about unsubscribing and then subscribing again just after `updateDoc` resolves, but then I realized when `onSnapshot` is initialized it does trigger a pull anyway..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't feasible, for the reasons that you explained yourself.  If you don't want to stay in sync with **any or all** changes to a document (and accept the billing consequences of that), then don't attach a listener to it at all, and instead find some other way to determine when you should `get()` the latest data.

Comment: No I still need to have listeners because opened apps should always reflect Firestore state, but why is the callback being called on the active page? when `updateDoc` is used on a page, one would expect to have a way to say "Ok firestore here I have the data locally because I am calling `updateDoc` so I don't need you to pull data from server"

Comment: That's just not how it works.  The listener gets invoked every time there is an update.  You can't change that unless you want to build your own version of the SDK and try to make it behave the way you want.